# Will code execute after CATCH block?

Tags: c++

This should be pretty easy question for many C++ experts.

I have some C++ code like below.

```
BOOL FindNumbersInObj() {

    BOOL ret = true;

    try {
        //Do bunch of things here...
        CMyObj pObj;

        try {
            pObj->GetMyObjectPtr();
        }
        catch (MyException ex) {
            pObj = NULL;
            ret = false;
        }
        ret = pObj->GetAllNumbers();
        //Do something here too....
    }
    catch (MyException ex) {
         //Log Error Message
         ret = false;
    } 
    return ret;
}
```

As you see there's a TRY inside another TRY. In the CATCH it sets the pObj to NULL. So is it possible that it will come out of the CATCH block and execute the line of code "**ret = pObj->GetAllNumbers();**"? If it does, then i would except the code to crash.

This is some leagcy/old code am looking at. Please give your opinion on having TRY inside another TRY.

And also if it hits a CATCH block will it go to the end of the function and call **return ret**?

Comment: Could you please fix your indentation?

Comment: `BOOL` is not in C++11. You probably mean `bool`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Probably using old Microsoft type aliases

Comment: Yes it uses Visual Studio on Microsoft APIs.

Answer (score 6):

> So is it possible that it will come out of the CATCH block and execute the line of code `ret = pObj->GetAllNumbers();`?

Yes.

> If it does, then [I] would [expect] the code to crash.

Me too.

> And also if it hits a CATCH block will it go to the end of the function and call return ret?

Yes.

Comment: You could have just tested it.

Comment: I don't have a way of testing it as it's some broken piece of code that cannot be build.

Comment: @DonK: Why do you care what it does if it's so broken that it doesn't build? It doesn't do anything!